# How to deploy uploadthing to vecel for my next js project

Tags: next.js, vercel

When i deploy my file uploader (use uploadthing) to vercel. I can not got response.
I got:
[UT] Call unsuccessful after 4 tries. Retrying in 8 seconds...

I find some info from uploadthing doc, but i don‘t know how to do that.
My callback runs in development and production, but not in Vercel preview deployments

By default, Vercel projects are configured to require authentication to access preview deployments. This means that our external server cannot access your application to trigger the callbacks you have set up in your file router.

To fix, this you can either disable this setting in your Vercel project, or—if you are paying for Advanced Deployment Protection—set a custom header

in the uploadthing dashboard that will allow uploadthing callbacks to bypass the authentication.
Configuring a custom header in the uploadthing dashboard

```
Go to your project's dashboard on uploadthing.com
Navigate to the "Settings" tab
Click on "Advanced Settings"
Click on the "Add Header" button
Enter the header name and value
Click "Save Changes"
```

WHich setting should I disable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just visit https://vercel.com/@ORGRANIZATION@/@PROJECT@/settings/deployment-protection and disable auth. The only other way is with headers but requires paid subscription to uploadthing.
[image]